# Using LINQ to search for value in an array of subobjects in JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq

So here is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Assignees": [
      {
        "ID": "1111",
        "IsPrimaryOffice": true
      },
      {
        "ID": "2222",
        "IsPrimaryOffice": false
      }
    ],
    "Height": "76",
    "Width": "78",
    "Top": "160",
    "Left": "99.5"
  },
  {
    "Assignees": [
      {
        "ID": "3333",
        "IsPrimaryOffice": true
      },
      {
        "ID": "4444",
        "IsPrimaryOffice": false
      }
    ],
    "Height": "11",
    "Width": "11",
    "Top": "11",
    "Left": "11"
  },
  {
    "Assignees": null,
    "Height": "22",
    "Width": "22",
    "Top": "22",
    "Left": "22"
  },
]
```

Where each main object in my array holds an array of sub-objects "`Assignees`".

So what I'm trying to do is to search each "`Assignees`" object in *its* array for a match on `ID`.

For example: I want to find the `Assignee` object which has an `ID` of "**3333**" and also has a **true** value for `IsPrimaryOffice` with LINQ. How can I do that? Here is what I came up with, but it always returns null:

```
mainObject.Where(x => 
                 x.Assignees != null &&
                 x.Assignees.Any(y => y.ID == "3333" && y.IsPrimaryOffice == true))
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Can anyone help me out here? Thank you in advance

Comment: have you deserialized the JSON into proper objects?

Comment: What are you trying to find? The assignee object (item in the inner Assignees array) or item from outer array which contains Assignee object with specified parameters in its Assignees array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created class using [json2sharp](http://json2csharp.com/) for provided json :

```
var jsonArray = "[{\"Assignees\":[{\"ID\": \"1111\",\"IsPrimaryOffice\": true      },
  {\"ID\": \"2222\",\"IsPrimaryOffice\": false      }    ],
\"Height\": \"76\",    \"Width\": \"78\",    \"Top\": \"160\",    \"Left\": \"99.5\"  },  
{    \"Assignees\": [      {\"ID\": \"3333\",\"IsPrimaryOffice\": true      },     
{\"ID\": \"4444\",\"IsPrimaryOffice\": false      }    ],
\"Height\": \"11\",    \"Width\": \"11\",    \"Top\": \"11\",    \"Left\": \"11\"  }]";
```

which generated as :

```
public class Assignee
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryOffice { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Assignee> Assignees { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Top { get; set; }
    public string Left { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I ran the below query

```
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonArray).ToObject<List<RootObject>>().Where(x => 
                 x.Assignees != null &&
                 x.Assignees.Any(y => y.ID == "3333" && y.IsPrimaryOffice == true))
          .FirstOrDefault();

foreach (var assignee in rootObj.Assignees)
{
        Console.WriteLine("ID = " + assignee.ID);
            Console.WriteLine("IsPrimaryOffice = " + assignee.IsPrimaryOffice);
}
```

then got the output as

> ID = 3333
>   IsPrimaryOffice = True
>   ID = 4444
>   IsPrimaryOffice = False

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked flawlessly. From your example, I completely understand it now - nested LINQ can get a bit confusing for me.